# Migrate terraform modules to updated provider format

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I inherited a codebase with all providers stored inside modules and am having a lot of trouble moving the providers out so that I can remove the resources created from modules.

The current design violates the rules outlined here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html and makes removing modules impossible.

My understanding of the migration steps is:

1. Create a provider for use at the top-level
2. Update module resources to use providers stored outside of the module
3. Remove module (with top-level provider persisting)

### Example module

An example `/route53-alias-record/main.ts` is:

```hcl
variable "evaluate_target_health" {
  default = true
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "env" {
  backend = "s3"

  config = {
    bucket = "<bucket>"
    key    = "infra-${var.environment}-${var.target}.tfstate"
    region = "<region>"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region              = data.terraform_remote_state.env.outputs.region
  allowed_account_ids = data.terraform_remote_state.env.outputs.allowed_accounts

  assume_role {
    role_arn = data.terraform_remote_state.env.outputs.aws_account_role
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "alias" {
  zone_id = data.terraform_remote_state.env.outputs.public_zone_id
  name    = var.fqdn
  type    = "A"

  alias {
    name                   = var.alias_name
    zone_id                = var.zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = var.evaluate_target_health
  }
}
```

### Starting usage

```hcl
module "api-dns-alias" {
  source      = "../environment/infra/modules/route53-alias-record"
  environment = "${var.environment}"
  zone_id     = "${module.service.lb_zone_id}"
  alias_name  = "${module.service.lb_dns_name}"
  fqdn        = "${var.environment}.example.com"
}
```

### Provider overriding

```hcl
## Same as inside module
provider "aws" {
  region              = data.terraform_remote_state.env.outputs.region
  allowed_account_ids = data.terraform_remote_state.env.outputs.allowed_accounts

  assume_role {
    role_arn = data.terraform_remote_state.env.outputs.aws_account_role
  }
}

module "api-dns-alias" {
  source      = "../environment/infra/modules/route53-alias-record"
  environment = "${var.environment}"
  zone_id     = "${module.service.lb_zone_id}"
  alias_name  = "${module.service.lb_dns_name}"
  fqdn        = "${var.environment}.example.com"

  providers = {
    aws = aws ## <-- pass in explicitly
  }
}
```

I was able to safely deploy with the providers set, but I do not believe that they are being used inside the module, which means the handshake still fails when I remove the module and the resources cannot be deleted.

I am looking for the steps needed to migrate to an outside provider so that I can safely remove resources.

I am currently working with terraform `0.12.24`

Comment: "handshake still fails when I remove the module and the resources cannot be deleted" What is the evidence you are seeing for this behavior? It really seems like you took the proper steps for this migration.

Comment: @MattSchuchard 1. Deploy as is, 2. Add provider explicitly, 3. Remove module (keep provider) --> error is the same as if I had just deleted the module. "Cannot find provider for ... as provider was deleted with module"

Comment: Without being able to interact with your config myself, best guess is that you need to start manually editing your state.

Comment: Manually editing using the cli tools, or just manually deleting/modifying references in the built object on s3? -- I haven't done that before. Any quick tips?